# The relationship between the order of an element in a group and the order of its image

Tags: finite-groups, conjectures, group-homomorphism

I am wondering if the following is true:

Let $G$ be a finite group, $g \in G$, and let $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism to another finite group $H$. Then $|g| = |\phi(g)| \cdot |k|$ for some element $k$ in $\ker \phi$.

To be specific, the element $k \in \ker \phi$ is taken to be $g^{|\phi(g)|}$. This clearly satisfies $\phi(g^{|\phi(g)|}) = \phi(g)^{|\phi(g)|} = e$.

I came up with a possible proof of this statement, but I wanted to see if anyone had counter-examples or insights on this issue.

The proof I had is to show that $|g|$ divides $|\phi(g) \cdot |k|$ and conversely, that $|\phi(g)|$ divides $\frac{|g|}{|k|}$, using the fact $|x|$ divides $n$ iff $x^n = e$.

Comment: Looks right to me.